# how to read byte by bye in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a buffer

```
uint8_t c[64] ={ 0xFF, 0xAA, 0x00} ;
```

I want to carry out a operation based on the byte value

```
for(uint8_t i=0; i<size;i++)
{
    if(0XAA == ???)
    {
    }
}
```

can anyone help me like how to read it byte by byte and perform the above.

Comment: Are you asking how to access an array element?

Comment: It is going to be slow progress in C programming if you have to ask fundamental questions about basic language syntax such as this.  Any C language reference will cover this.

Comment: No one called "Cliff" around here - _that's_ rude!  You are mistaking good advice for rudeness.  It was intended to help you avoid down-votes (not from me), and to point out the inefficiency of learning by posting questions on widely available information.   Not knowing a thing is fair enough, but judgement on the most appropriate method of filling that gap is critical - read a book or tutorial to start with.  SO would not prosper if it were filled with questions such at this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question. It seems that you have a buffer consisting of 64 elements and you want to access each of them in a loop. You can address such buffer like this:
c[0],c[1],c[2].....c[63]

For example:

```
for(uint8_t index = 0; index < 64; index++)  {
    if(c[index] == 0xFF) DoThis
    else if(c[index] == 0xAA) DoThat
    else if(c[index] == 0x00) DoWhatElse
    .... }
```

You can also use a switch case instead of if's. Take a look: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are equivalent to `uint8`, then presumably [each element *is* a byte](https://doc.embedded-wizard.de/uint8-uint16-uint32-type?v=9.00).

```
for(uint8_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    if(0XAA == c[i])
    {
        foo();
    }
}
```

Once you've read all 64 bytes, your buffer `c` has been processed and you can fetch a new one, cleanup the old one, etc. You can directly compare the array elements with octal values because to the compiler, a number is a number and 0xAA is the same as 170. You don't have to treat it differently just because it's in octal notation.